# syntax error, unexpected $end in PHP, and I already checked '}'

Tags: php

```
<?php
  require_once('Auth/Auth-1.6.4/Auth.php');

  class MyAuth extends Auth
  {
    function custom_login( $username = null, $status = null )
    {
      if( $status == AUTH_WRONG_LOGIN )
        $status_msg = 'nameORpasswordWRONG';
      else
        $status_msg = '';

      echo <<<LOGIN_FORM
      LOGIN_FORM;
    }
  }
?>
```

I get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected $end

I got this error when I added the following lines:

```
echo <<<LOGIN_FORM  
LOGIN_FORM;
```

I checked `}`, but they seem to correct. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your going to have to expand a bit more on this. Why is this happening what did you add echo to, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

There must be no whitespace between the new line and the closing LOGIN_FORM;

See the big warning in the [documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 4):

[Heredoc style string enders *cannot* be indented.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 3):

When using [HEREDOCs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), the end tag must be on the line by itself.  No white space before it.

```
<?php
  require_once('Auth/Auth-1.6.4/Auth.php');

  class MyAuth extends Auth
  {
    function custom_login( $username = null, $status = null )
    {
      if( $status == AUTH_WRONG_LOGIN )
        $status_msg = 'nameORpasswordWRONG';
      else
        $status_msg = '';

      echo <<<LOGIN_FORM
LOGIN_FORM;
    }
  }
?>
```

Make sure there's no whitespace before `LOGIN_FORM;`.

Answer (score 2):

`LOGIN_FORM` has to be flush with the very left.  [See the PHP documentation on HEREDOCs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)